# exception for NPE org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.addDependenciesToCurrentModule

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-pipelines

Im creating a jenkins pipeline and I need to publish buildInfo in artifactory using artifactory plugin, this project has submodules with their own POM inside.

My pipeline is similar to this

```js
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git 'https://github.com/example/repo.git'
            }
        }

        stage('Build and Publish') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def server = Artifactory.server('artifactory-server')
                    def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()

                    rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local', server: server
                    rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo: 'libs-release', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot', server: server

                    rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = true

                    def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install'

                    // Publish build info to Artifactory
                    server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
I keep getting this exception
```

```html
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.addDependenciesToCurrentModule(BuildInfoRecorder.java:619)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.addModuleToBuild(BuildInfoRecorder.java:466)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.finalizeModule(BuildInfoRecorder.java:389)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.projectSucceeded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:208)
```

Any Idea how to avoid this exception or a way to overwrite the NPE in BuildInfoRecorder?

Im using artifactory plugin 3.18.3 and using Jenkins 2.397

Comment: You have to tell us at least, what versions of Jenkins and artifactory plugin you are using. It can't be the newest one, it's a blank line [in `BuildInfoRecorder` line 594](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/blob/master/build-info-extractor-maven3/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/extractor/maven/BuildInfoRecorder.java#L594)

Comment: hi @Sascha , im using artifactory plugin 3.18.3 and using Jenkins 2.397

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/blob/build-info-extractor-2.39.8/build-info-extractor-maven3/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/extractor/maven/BuildInfoRecorder.java#L619) it has to be `dependencyParentsMaps` that's null.  
As the only reference to that field I found [this `EventSpy` class](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/blob/e2d01569a5ababd106679a062c4c620a696179de/build-info-extractor-maven3/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/extractor/maven/DependencyResolutionSpy.java#L32). So it looks to me that that event does not happen before the other method is called.

Comment: You should create an issue either in [the plugin](https://issues.jenkins.io/issues/?jql=resolution%20is%20EMPTY%20and%20component%3D15689) or in the [used lib](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/issues).

Comment: What is the Maven version?

Comment: change the maven version and worked, thanks @yahavi

Answer (score 0):

I change the maven version to 3.5 and it worked correctly

Comment: Could you please share the Maven version that caused this issue?